Seeing JDATA is missing or invalid errors below are two methods I tried using
Method 1:
def get_positions(susertoken, actid):
    url = base_url + "PositionBook"
    data = {
        "uid": "TEST18",
        "actid": actid
    }
    payload = {
        "jData": json.dumps(data),
        "jKey": susertoken
    }

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    response_text = response.text
    print(response_text)

Method 2:
def get_positions(susertoken, actid):
    url = base_url+"PositionBook"
    data = {
    "jData": '{"uid":"TEST18", "actid":"' + actid + '"}',
    "jKey": susertoken
    }
    
    payload = "jData="+json.dumps(data)

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    response_json = response.json()
    print(response_json)

API, I am using is here - https://shoonya.com/api-documentation#positions-book
login is successful and susertoken and actid are correct.
